# How do I control jQuery UI to stay open on active links?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI for the sidebar navigation here: http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/

I would like to be able to keep the accordion open on the current active section. So for example if I am on this page: http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/inland_empire_utilities_agency, the **Infrastructure** accordion will remain open.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="accordion">
<div>
<h3><a href="#">Infrastructure</a></h3>
<div>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/green_valley_ranch">Green Valley Ranch</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/irvine_spectrum">Irvine Spectrum</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/lynwood">Lynwood</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/inland_empire_utilities_agency">Inland Empire Utilities Agency</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/center_for_regenerative_studies">Center for Regenerative Studies</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/agriscapes">Agriscapes</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/sepulveda_basin_wildlife_area">Sepulveda Basin Wildlife Area</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/upper_newport_bay_regional_park">Upper Newport Bay Regional Park</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/los_angeles_world_airports">Los Angeles World Airports</a></p>
</div>  
</div>
<div>...
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active:false });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
        function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
        });
});
</script>
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-navigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look if url is presented in href of any of the links, and then show the corresponding div

its not perfect, but at least it is generic, you can modify it to your needs...

I've made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKgsQ/1/

**EDIT:**

Here's the code you must place in $(function(){  });, after initializing accordion

```
var arr = window.location.toString().split('/');
var currentUrl = arr[arr.length -1]; 
$("#accordion a").each(function(){
    arr = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
    var linkUrl = arr[arr.length -1]; //get last part
    if(linkUrl == currentUrl) 
        $(this).css('background-color','yellow').closest('div').show();
});
```

Comment: This is closer. The div does stay open, however, when I click on other links in other sections, the first one still stays open.

Comment: That's because I've hard-coded current url, to work in the fiddle: `var currentUrl = "green_valley_ranch";`. I'll change it in my post

Comment: That made the difference. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can hold on to the index of the accordion item selected, you can use the `activate` method for the accordion plug-in.  Your modified jQuery could look like this:

```
$(function(){

    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active:false });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
        function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
        });

    $("#accordion").accordion('option', 'activate', 0);
});
```

This will cause the 1st accordion item (index 0) to be open when loaded.

**UPDATE**: Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/3Au94/1/) to a jsFiddle I put together showing how to use the accordion's `activate` method.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, I can set a class on the div based on the URL. For example, if infrastructure == segment_2 class="active". Would something like that work?

Comment: You can use `accordion('option','active')` to get the active index of the accordion.  (It will return `false` if nothing is open.).  If you hold on to that value, then you can pass it in to the `activate` method.  I was going to put a link to a fiddle for this, but jsFiddle is extremely slow at the moment.  I'll update it as soon as it comes up for me.  :)

Comment: Please do let me know when you have it working. This will be very helpful.

Comment: Updated my answer to fix a typo and also linked to the fiddle I put together.  I'd go with something like this approach rather than on setting a class and using a selector to get to it.

Comment: How are you passing the information from page to page (or call to call)?  If you pass it as a querystring variable (not the cleanest, but may be a start), you could grab it and set it during the initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block !important;` on the link div.

```
<div style="display: block !important;">
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/green_valley_ranch">Green Valley Ranch</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/irvine_spectrum">Irvine Spectrum</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/lynwood">Lynwood</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/inland_empire_utilities_agency">Inland Empire Utilities Agency</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/center_for_regenerative_studies">Center for Regenerative Studies</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/agriscapes">Agriscapes</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/sepulveda_basin_wildlife_area">Sepulveda Basin Wildlife Area</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/upper_newport_bay_regional_park">Upper Newport Bay Regional Park</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.imadesign.com/dev/work/infrastructure/los_angeles_world_airports">Los Angeles World Airports</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this won't work because accordion changes style attribute, thus loosing display:block. It must be set with javascript.

Comment: You have added it on the wrong div ;) You must add it on the div after <h3><a href="#">Infrastructure</a></h3>

Comment: Claude, I added it to the div after the h3 and it still stays closed.

Comment: The Infrastructure stays now open. You must now add a function that dynamically sets this attribute to the section where you are currently in.

Comment: Hi Claude. I am using Firefox and no matter which link I click on in the Infrastructure section, it does not remain open after it navigates to that page.

Answer (score -1):

From the [jQuery UI Accordian documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default)

> NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an
>   accordion
>
> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at
>   the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are
>   looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be
>   open, don't use this. Usually it can be written with a few lines of
>   jQuery instead, something like this:
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>         $('.accordion.head').click(function() {
>         $(this).next().toggle();
>         return false;
>     }).next().hide(); });
>
> Or animated:
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){    $('.accordion
>   .head').click(function() {        $(this).next().toggle('slow');      return
>   false;    }).next().hide(); });

Comment: Hi AdmSteck, in fact, I only want one section open at a time. I just want the "active" section open - which depends on the current active page.

Comment: If only the active section is open, how will the user navigate to a different section?  Or do you mean that when the user is not actively using the menu, the active section should be open and only close when the user is using the menu?

Comment: The accordion should still continue to function. It is just the depending on the current active page, that links parent div will be open.